# Powershell PipelineVariable is using last value

Tags: powershell

I am occuring strange error. I am building query and I am getting strange bug.
When I execute this Powershell command:

```
Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_DiskDrive -Filter 'MediaType = "Removable Media"' -KeyOnly | ForEach-Object {$Details = $_.PNPDeviceID;$_}|
Get-CimAssociatedInstance -Association Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition -KeyOnly |
Get-CimAssociatedInstance -Association Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition |
Select-Object Name, @{ n='SerialNumber'; e={$Details.split("\")[-1].split("&")[0]}}
```

My $Details variable is the same for both object

```
Name SerialNumber
---- ------------
F:   4C530001090425122264
E:   4C530001090425122264
```

More friendly example:

```
Get-CimInstance Win32_Diskdrive -PipelineVariable disk |
Get-CimAssociatedInstance -ResultClassName Win32_DiskPartition -PipelineVariable partition |
Get-CimAssociatedInstance -ResultClassName Win32_LogicalDisk |
Select-Object @{n='Disk';e={$disk.deviceid}},
@{n='DiskSize';e={$disk.size}},
@{n='DiskModel';e={$disk.model}},
@{n='Partition';e={$partition.name}},
@{n='RawSize';e={$partition.size}},
@{n='DriveLetter';e={$_.DeviceID}},
VolumeName,Size,FreeSpace
```

Everything is fine till I pipe everything to first Association, after this $Details variable is the same for both objects.

Comment: @mklement0 & `Mikart Aerang` - my tone was needlessly sharp ... and needlessly terse. please accept my apology for that. [*blush*] ///// the Answer by `mklement0` covers why i was so astonished ... and i now see that it was NOT as obvious as i thot it was. ///// please, flag this & all related comments for deletion after you have read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your approach** - whether via a variable set in a `ForEach-Object` block or via one set by the
[`-PipelineVariable` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#pipelinevariable) - **only works if all subsequent cmdlets in the same pipeline process and output their input objects *one by one*, *as they're being received*.**

The approach **does *not* work with cmdlets that (must) *aggregate* all input first**, before passing on results, prominent examples of which are `Sort-Object` and `Group-Object`.

For what *may* be performance reasons, **`Get-CimAssociatedInstance` too seems to perform such aggregation**: it *collects* all objects received via the pipeline first, before producing output based on them. The net result is that `$Details` / `$disk` only contains information about the *last* `Win32_DiskDrive` instance in the rest of the pipeline.

**Workaround**:

*At the expense of performance*, **wrap your `Get-CimAssociatedInstance` calls in `ForEach-Object` blocks in order to have them process each input object *one by one***.

Here's a simplified example:

```bash
# NOTE: Get-CimAssociatedInstance must be called *inside a ForEach-Object* block.
Get-CimInstance Win32_Diskdrive -PipelineVariable drive |
  ForEach-Object { $_ | Get-CimAssociatedInstance -ResultClassName Win32_DiskPartition } |
    Select-Object Name, @{ n='PNPDeviceId'; e = { $drive.PnpDeviceId } }
```

You'll see something like the following, showing disk-appropriate PNP device IDs for each partition:

```
Name                  PNPDeviceId
----                  -----------
Disk #0, Partition #0 SCSI\DISK&VEN_VMWARE_&PROD_VMWARE_VIRTUAL_S\5&1EC51BF7&0&000000
Disk #0, Partition #1 SCSI\DISK&VEN_VMWARE_&PROD_VMWARE_VIRTUAL_S\5&1EC51BF7&0&000000
Disk #1, Partition #0 USBSTOR\DISK&VEN_PI-201&PROD_SATA/USB20_DRIVE&REV_1.04\071008DP1D00DFG0484N____&0
```

Without the `ForEach-Object` wrapper around `Get-CimAssociatedInstance`, the `PNPDeviceId` would all be the same (the *last* disk's value).

**Note**: The `ForEach-Object` workaround only works with cmdlets that can meaningfully process *individual input objects*. It wouldn't work for cmdlets such as `Sort-Object`, which *must collect all inputs first* (to produce sorting *across* all input objects).